# canvas.scale(mScaleFactor,mScaleFactor,detector.getFocusX(),detector.getFocusY()) dragging limit messing up?

Tags: android, zooming, scale

I have tried to develop a custom `ImageView` by searching on google and here on SO.

Everything is working fine except when I try to scale the canvas using `mdetector.getFocusX()` and `mdetector.getFocusY()`.
The zoom happens properly, but the dragging calculations get messed up.

When I use `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor,mScaleFactor,gx,gy)` in my code below, drag happens all over the place and a black screen behind can be seen.
I want to limit the drag to the screen bounds.

In my code that bound calculation works for the Zoom in, when `canvas.scale(mScaleFactor,mScaleFactor)` i.e.: it works properly when it is zoomed from `(0,0)` without using pivot points .

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/* @description : Custom View Zoom
 *
 */

public class ZoomView extends ImageView {

    // Maximum and Minimum Zoom
    private static float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static float MAX_ZOOM = 3.0f;

    //Different Operation to be used 
    private final int NONE_OPERATION=0;
    private final int DRAG_OPERATION=1;
    private final int ZOOM_OPERATION=2;
    private float mWidth= 1047;
    private float mHeight=800; 
    private boolean dragged=true;

    // Mode to select the operation
    private int mode;

    //Track X and Y coordinate of the finger when it first touches the screen
    private float mInitialX = 0f;
    private float mInitialY = 0f;

    //Track the amount to translate(Drag) the canvas along the X and the Y coordinate
    private float mTranslateX = 0f;
    private float mTranslateY = 0f;

    //Track the last translated X and the Y coordinate while panning so that canvas does not get the jerk (Issue was happening when we change the position again and again ) 
    private float mPreviousTranslateX = 0f;
    private float mPreviousTranslateY = 0f;

    //ScalingFactor i.e. Amount of Zoom
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.0f;
    float gx=0,gy=0;





    private ScaleGestureDetector mDetector;


    // Called if used from code 
    public ZoomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        // Intialize ScaleGestureDetector
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ZoomListener());

    }

    //Called if used from XML
    public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ZoomListener());

    }

    //Everything that is going to reflect on the screen will happen in on draw
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    //Save the canvas to set the scaling factor returned from detector
        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,gx,gy);
        Log.d("Print", "mScaleFactor::" + mTranslateX);
        Log.d("Print", " mTranslateX::" + (mScaleFactor - 1) * mWidth);
    //Check the bound that we never pan past the top of left edge of the
    if((mTranslateX) < 0) {
        mTranslateX=0;

    }
    ////Check the right bound.
    // eg : Height of display is 1280. When it is zoom by 2 it is 1280 . when it is zoom by 3 it is  2560
    // Compare translateX times -1 to (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth. 
    //If translateX is greater than that value, then it has gone over the bound. So we set the value of translateX to (1 - scaleFactor) times the display width. 
    // Notice that the terms are interchanged... it's the same as doing -1 * (scaleFactor - 1) * displayWidth
    else if((mTranslateX) > (mScaleFactor - 1) * mWidth){
        mTranslateX=(mScaleFactor - 1 )* mWidth;
        Log.d("Print", " InDraw mTranslateX::" + mTranslateX);
    }

    if((mTranslateY)< 0) 
        mTranslateY=0;
/*  else if((mTranslateY) > (mScaleFactor - 1) * mHeight)
        mTranslateY= (mScaleFactor-1)* mHeight;*/



    //divide by the scale factor here,
    //otherwise it will end up with excessive panning based on our zoom level since the translation amount also gets scaled according to how much we've zoomed into the canvas.
      canvas.translate(mTranslateX / mScaleFactor, mTranslateY / mScaleFactor);    

    // Draw anything more if needed here ....

      // Restore the canvas to balance the save Canvas which removes all the last modification before save.


      super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.restore();
    }


    //handle the touch event of the view with the detector to get the scalingFactor and also keep the track of 
    // the touch events like drag and zoom event using booleans 
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // Handles all type of motion-events possible
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Event occurs when the first finger is pressed on the Screen

            // setting the mode to Drag Operation
            mode = DRAG_OPERATION;

            // Store the initial X and Y of the first finger when touches on the Screen. Take the difference with the previous translation so as to avoid the jerk in canvas.
            //Initial difference will be X and Y since previousTranslation will be ZERO.
            mInitialX = event.getX() - mPreviousTranslateX;
            mInitialY = event.getY() - mPreviousTranslateY;

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Event occurs when the finger move across the screen and also when the finger is kept pressed on the screen

            // Update the translate value constantly as the event is occured at every move
            mTranslateX = event.getX() - mInitialX;             // Translate value is calculated by diff from current and initial
            mTranslateY = event.getY() - mInitialY;





            Log.d("Print", " TranslateX::" + mTranslateX + " Translate Y::" + mTranslateY);

            // If finger is kept pressed it will still consider the move so to avoid that use this value
            //Initial X and Initial Y can not be used directly because they were adjusted  using the previous translation values. So need to add those
            // values to InitialX and InitialY so that the actual coordinates of the finger are retrieved.
            // Using distance Forumla
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX() - (mInitialX + mPreviousTranslateX), 2) + Math.pow(event.getY() - (mInitialY + mPreviousTranslateY), 2));
                if(distance > 0) {
            dragged = true;

            } 



            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //Event occurs when the second finger is pressed down


            // If second finger is pressed on the screen with the first set the Mode to Zoom operation
            mode=ZOOM_OPERATION;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            //Event occurs when all the finger are taken of the screen

            //If all the fingers are taken up there will be no operation 
            mode = NONE_OPERATION;
            dragged= false;
            // All the operations are done.Store the previousTranslate value here. ( Might not need at the time of second finger down ??)
            mPreviousTranslateX = mTranslateX;
            mPreviousTranslateY = mTranslateY;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            // Event occurs when the second finger is taken of the screen while first finger is pressed 


            // Second finger is taken up stop zooming and again Drag Operation 
            mode=DRAG_OPERATION;
            break;
        }

        // give the event to the mDetector to get the scaling Factor
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        //We need to invalidate the canvas to redraw itself for the changes.Here we need to invalidate only when zoom is done and drag operation has happened 
        //or else for the Zoom which was happening in the onScale function 
        if((mode==DRAG_OPERATION && mScaleFactor!=1f && dragged ) || mode==ZOOM_OPERATION)
        {

            invalidate();
        }



        // we are handling the touch event 
        return true;
    }



/* @name : ZoomListener
 * @description : Class which defines the listener for ScaleGestureDetector while extending abstract 
 * 
 */
    private class ZoomListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

/*
 * ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 *
 * @description: Method gives the scaleFactor from the detector
 *
 * ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 */
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // getting the scaleFactor from the detector
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();              // gives the scaling factor from the previous scaling to the current
            Log.d("Print", "detector scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);


            gx = detector.getFocusX();
            gy = detector.getFocusY();

            // Limit the scale factor in the MIN and MAX bound
            mScaleFactor= Math.max(Math.min(mScaleFactor, MAX_ZOOM),MIN_ZOOM);
            Log.d("Print", "Bounded scaling Factor" + mScaleFactor);

            /*//Force canvas to redraw itself only if the one event is to happen (say Zooming only ) else do not invalidate here for multi operations
               As what we de for scrolling or panning will not reflect here. So we will add this in onDraw method 
            invalidate();*/

            // we have handle the onScale 
            return true;
        }

        @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

                super.onScaleEnd(detector);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey dude,nicely written and commented it will help beginners. Hope you get bounty for this so it can be easy for beginner to understand

Comment: have you found the answer, as I am also facing exactly same situation...

Comment: @kamal_tech_view : I was working on some other project couldnt make it work ...as soon as i will ...I will buzz ..if u come across with the same do tell me ...

Comment: it's pretty easy... in my case it is a game board.. so, I think the way may not be useful but I think this will help you https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
public void checkZoom(){
    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);
    float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    if(scaleX > MAX_ZOOM) {
        setZoom(MAX_ZOOM);
    } 
    else if(scaleX < MIN_ZOOM) {
        setZoom(MIN_ZOOM);
    }
    limitCorners();
}

private void limitCorners() {
    viewWidth = this.getWidth();
    viewHeight = this.getHeight();
    float []m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, getImageWidth());
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, getImageHeight());
    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0) {
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }
    matrix.getValues(m);
    if (getImageWidth() < viewWidth) {
        m[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = (viewWidth - getImageWidth()) / 2;
    }
    if (getImageHeight() < viewHeight) {
        m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = (viewHeight - getImageHeight()) / 2;
    }
    matrix.setValues(m);
}

private float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }
    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}
```

/** Get the width of image (bitmapWidth*Zoom)*/

```
float getImageWidth(){
    float []m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    return m[Matrix.MSCALE_X]*bitmap.getWidth();
}
```

/** Get the Height of image (bitmapHeight*Zoom)*/

```
float getImageHeight(){
    float []m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    return m[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]*bitmap.getHeight();
}
```